# How do I enable Windows special permissions in the security tab?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I need to enable the special permissions on the basic tab of security properties, I tried using anything, `icacls cmd`, etc.
Is there a way to check that box?

[image: Security properties tab]

Comment: It does appear you have edit permission on that particular folder, which is the reason, you cannot edit which users and user groups have which permissions. This is expected from a folder within System32.

Comment: **does not** appear....

Answer (score 10):

"Special permissions" is an aggregate entry that means "**any** weird combination of permissions that doesn't exactly match one of the 'basic' permission groups".

Go to the "Advanced" section, edit a permission entry, then click "Show advanced permissions". You'll see that e.g. "Modify" actually consists of multiple permission bits (Write Data; Append Data; Write Attributes; &c.) – if you enable only *some* of them, but not enough to fully complete the "Modify" group, then that will be shown as having "Special permissions" enabled.

Therefore it doesn't make sense to try to "enable Special permissions" as it doesn't *do* anything specific – it's the specific advanced permission bits that actually grant the access.

(Or, perhaps more accurately, "Special permissions" indicates that something is **missing** from the standard groups. This is why it's impossible to have both "Full Control" and "Special Permissions" checked at the same time.)

Answer (score 6):

Each file or folder has 18 types of permissions.
6 of those are "basic permissions"  and are visible under the
Security tab. 12 are "advanced permissions" that are set
automatically and are exposed in advanced mode only.

If you make any changes to the advanced permissions, then
the change is flagged by a tick mark in the "Special Permissions"
box.

To arrive at the advanced permissions:

- In the Security tab click Advanced
- Click Add
- If the Owner field is empty, click Change,
  enter your account-name and click Check Names, then OK
- Click Show advanced permissions.

[image]